# Error when creating a table in MySql: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')'

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating a new database, and dbeaver keeps giving me an error when I try to create the table band_members. The error pertains specifically to the line: MEMBER_NAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL. The first table, band, was created just fine with the exact same syntax.

I'm running DBeaver 6.1.5 for MySql 8+

```
create table band(BAND_ID int not null auto_increment, 
BAND_NAME VARCHAR(30) not null, primary key(BAND_ID));

create table band_members(MEMBER_ID int not null auto_increment, 
MEMBER_NAME VARCHAR(30) not null,
BAND_ID INT,
MEMBER_ROLE VARCHAR(30), primary key(MEMBER_ID), foreign key(BAND_ID));
```

I expected the second table band_members to be created, but instead it gives me the error in the title.

Comment: Sure it's not from the foreign key bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usually when you create a foreign key in the create table you refer from where it will come from, so it would look something like this:

```
create table band(BAND_ID int not null auto_increment, 
BAND_NAME VARCHAR(30) not null, primary key(BAND_ID));
create table band_members(MEMBER_ID int not null auto_increment, 
MEMBER_NAME VARCHAR(30) not null,
BAND_ID INT,
MEMBER_ROLE VARCHAR(30), primary key(MEMBER_ID), foreign key(BAND_ID) references band(BAND_ID));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `reference_definition` part of your `FOREIGN KEY` clause (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)). Change it to this:

```
foreign key(BAND_ID) references band(BAND_ID)
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=295573ba0107900e26c227eb8c64fa1f)

Answer (score 0):

You need the full `references` portion:

```
create table band_members(
    MEMBER_ID int not null auto_increment, 
    MEMBER_NAME VARCHAR(30) not null,
    BAND_ID INT,
    MEMBER_ROLE VARCHAR(30),
    primary key(MEMBER_ID),
    foreign key(BAND_ID) references band(band_id)
);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=25c60b70ad31d0840c1e6e4375bf4e36) is a db<>fiddle.